# What does this JDK error message means?

Tags: java

I am not familiar with `Java` and `JDK`. I have a java program as a `.jar` file that i want to run it in `ubuntu 12.04`. I use this command:

```
java -jar SAStoSEP.jar
```

But i get this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at SAStoSeP.main(SAStoSeP.java:56)
    ... 5 more
```

What does this error means?

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `SAStoSeP.java:56`?

Comment: No. unfortunately  this program is closed source

Comment: You are probably missing an argument.

Comment: @HesamQodsi If it's closed source why do you ask here? We can't guess what your code is, if you want help you have to show the code. **Plus** Java is fully decompilable, so making a jar will not make your program _closed source_.

Comment: @ BackSlash you are right. I am not familiar with java.

Comment: @HesamQodsi It's ok, I just wanted to let you know that making _closed source_ applications is not possible with java. You can of course obfuscate your code, so that it becomes hard to read, but it will always be decompilable. If you want it to be closed source you have to code with some language like C, C++ or other languages that compile into a native executable

Comment: @BackSlash - 1) I don't think he is *making* a closed source program.  He is *using* one.  2) The fact that you can (try to) decompile a Java program does NOT mean that there aren't closed-source Java programs: a) decompilation doesn't always work, b) decompilation is *probably* forbidden by the license, and c) it *cannot* give you the *original* source code.

Comment: To expand on what Thomas Jungblut is saying, it seems you are missing a command-line argument.  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s thrown from within `main` methods are often because the code is trying to access command-line arguments when there aren't any or there are fewer than it expects.  Try `java -jar SAStoSEP.jar <some argument>`.  It looks to me as if you have the misfortune to be dealing with a JAR file so poorly written that it can't even tell you if you've missed a command-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

In the `JarRsrcLoader.main` method a method invocation is done usinig refelction (JarRsrcLoader.java:58) to invoke `SAStoSeP.main`.

While invoking that method an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) was thrown (SAStoSeP.java:56). This Exception was wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException`.

From the [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) javadoc:

> throws InvocationTargetException - if the underlying method throws an exception.

Comment: And how can i deal with this problem?

Comment: @Hesam Qodsi I guess that the reflection call uses the programm arguments and you forgot to provide one at the command line. Can you post the source code of SAStoSeP?

Answer (score 1):

In your `main()` method of `SAStoSeP` class, you are trying to access the first element of an empty list. Thus, you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It has nothing to do with JDK. Possible causes are :

- The program reads argument from the command line, and you are not providing any.
- This is not the `main` class you should run. You are launching a *runnable* JAR file, but it could contain many `main()` method.

Comment: Since he is launching using `-jar`, it is the JAR itself (i.e. the MANIFEST.MF) that is deciding on the entry point.  Surely, it will choose one the makes sense ...

Answer (score 0):

It means that on line 56 of SAStoSeP (in the main method), there was an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown.

Because the main method was invoked via reflection, it was wrapped in an InvocationTargetException, which is why the stack trace is split into two sections.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. Check your code at line 56 at SastoSep.java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a proprietary project, we cannot tell you what is causing a particular exception to be thrown.  That would entail looking at the source code!!

The correct way to solve this is to ask the support folks for the product to explain the problem and tell you how to avoid it.  For a start, anything that throws a generic exception to the user like that is arguably a bug.  And if you have paid money for the right to use a product, you have a reasonable expectation of reliability ... and support.

However, given the method that is throwing the exception ... and the exception itself ... I would guess is that SAStoSeP is expecting some command line arguments.  (A poorly written `main(String[] args)` method might attempt to access `arg[0]` without checking `args.length`.  That would result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` at index 0.  And you didn't supply *any* arguments ...) So check the documentation on how you are supposed to that command.